Exists $x$ that is "far away" from $a_1$, $a_2\dots$, $a_n$

Let $a_1$, $a_2\dots$, $a_n\in[0,1]$. Prove that there exists $x\in[0,1]$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{(x-a_i)^2}\le40n^2$.

Since I cannot easily determine the optimal $x$, I decided to use the method of expected value.
If $x$ is evenly distributed on $[0,1]$,
$$\mathbb E\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{(x-a_i)^2}\right)=\int_0^1\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{(x-a_i)^2}\operatorname dx=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_0^1\frac1{(x-a_i)^2}\operatorname dx,$$
which is obviously divergent.
So a particular probability density function is required. For values near some $a_i$, the probability density must be smaller, because such values are not optimal for $x$. Hence I tried to use the function
$$f(x)=\frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(x-a_i)^2}{\int_0^1\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(t-a_i)^2\operatorname dt}.$$
Now we need to show that $\int_0^1\left(f(x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{(x-a_i)^2}\right)\operatorname dx\le40n^2$. I am not sure if this is correct.

Can you detail the method of the expected value ? And especially why it seems sufficient to deal with the expectancy ?

I think in order to apply the transfer theorem $ E(\phi(X))=\int\phi(x)f(x)dx$, $\phi$ need to be integrable. But  $\phi : x \to \sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{ (x-a_i)^2} $ isn't on $[0,1]$

Yes, I think it does not work

Have you tried computer runs ?

Not yet, but I think that attempting to find such an $x$ helps little. @EDX

This form inspires me, the use of $\tan$ and $\cos()$ since $1/\cos()^2=1+\tan()^2$. After that I haven't been able yet to find egality on existence.

Given a parameter $\delta>0$, let $S_\delta$ be the set of all $x\in[0,1]$ that is at least $\delta$ away from each $a_i$. Then the measure $m_\delta$ of $S_\delta$ is at least $1-2\delta n$, and in particular $S_\delta$ is nonempty when $\delta<\frac1{2n}$. Set the probability density function $f(x)$ to be the constant $\frac1{m_\delta}$ on $S_\delta$ (and $0$ on $[0,1]\setminus S_\delta$). Then
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{(x-a_i)^2} \,dx \le \int_{-\infty}^{a_i-\delta} \frac1{m_\delta(x-a_i)^2} \,dx + \int_{a_i+\delta}^\infty \frac1{m_\delta(x-a_i)^2} \,dx = \frac2{m_\delta\delta},
$$
and so
$$
\int_{S_\delta} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{(x-a_i)^2} \,dx = \int_0^1 m_\delta f(x)\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{(x-a_i)^2} \,dx \le \frac{2n}\delta.
$$
It follows that there exists $x\in S_\delta$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{(x-a_i)^2} \le \frac{2n}{m_\delta\delta} \le \frac{2n}{(1-2\delta n)\delta}.
$$
The optimal choice to minimze the right-hand size is $\delta=\frac1{4n}$, which yields the upper bound $16n^2$.

Can this be generalised to evaluate $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{|x-a_i|^k}$ particularly when $k$ is an odd positive integer?

I feel like it can—give it a try :)
